# No value insert in the column SQL

Tags: database, postgresql, insert

I've got some polygons in a table, and I want to convert them into an area and add the result in a row.

```
INSERT INTO citydb.surfaces(foot_p)
SELECT st_area(geom)
FROM citydb.surfaces
WHERE class_id = 33;
```

It returns this:

```
INSERT 0 110521

Query returned successfully in 677 msec.
```

But the column is empty.

Comment: Then probably `geom` was NULL for all these rows. Some sample data to reproduce the problem would help.

Comment: geom wasn't NULL because when i run the code without the INSERT INTO the data output window shows the result

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to fill a new column for the existing rows of the table, but what you are doing is to add new rows, in which all columns except for `foot_p` (and columns with a `DEFAULT` value) will be NULL.

You probably mean to do

```
UPDATE citydb.surfaces
SET foot_p = st_area(geom);
```

This will modify the existing rows.

This update will bloat your table considerably, so consider running

```
VACUUM (FULL) citydb.surfaces;
```

afterwards.